# Azure Managing Interrupted/partial blob uploads

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

I'm uploading bobs to my azure cloud storage using the following way. The problem I'm facing is, if a user exits the web application or if the upload gets interrupted, the partially uploaded blob still remains on the storage. What is the way of handling interrupted blob uploads in Azure?

Code:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(cloudString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
container.CreateIfNotExists();
container.SetPermissions(
new BlobContainerPermissions
{
        PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
 });
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(uniqueBlobName);
blockBlob.UploadFromByteArray(f, 0, f.Length);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When it comes to uploading files as block blobs, there are two possible scenarios:

1. **File is uploaded without being split into chunks** - Let's say a user is uploading a file without splitting it in chunks and in the middle of upload process user closes the browser. In this case, nothing will happen because the blob is not saved yet in blob storage.
2. **File is uploaded in chunks** - This is the case with large files where the upload is happening in chunks. Assuming a scenario where some chunks are uploaded and after that user terminates the upload process. In this case, there are two possible solutions:

1) **You do nothing** - If you don't do anything, chunks that are uploaded but not committed gets deleted by storage service automatically after 7 (or 14) days. Downside of this approach is that you would pay for these bytes for those days.

2) **You can programmatically delete uncommitted blobs** - You can get a list of uncommitted blobs in a container and delete those blobs. One thing I would suggest is that you find uncommitted blobs that have not been modified for a certain time so that you're not deleting the blobs which are still being uploaded.

**UPDATE**

I had a chance to play with uncommitted blobs. When you list blobs with `BlobListingDetails.UncommittedBlobs`, it will return both committed and uncommitted blobs. One way to identify an uncommitted blob is by checking it's `ETag` property. In my little experiment, I found that `ETag` property will be `null` and blob length to be `0 bytes` in case of an uncommitted blob.

[image]

Comment: But then what if the blobs are successfully uploaded blobs and they are still marked as 'not been modified for a certain time'. They'd be deleted as well. I was hoping there would be a Azure API based solution for handling these?

Comment: Aaah ... for some reason I thought that when you use `BlobListingDetails.UncommittedBlobs`, you will only get uncommitted blobs but I just checked the documentation and it returns both committed and uncommitted blobs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.bloblistingdetails.aspx) so it becomes a bit tricky. One option is to do dual listing - one with `BlobListingDetails.None` and other with `BlobListingDetails.UncommittedBlobs` and then remove the common blobs. The list you're left with is just uncommitted blobs. Let me give it a try though.

Comment: Updated my answer to find another way to identify uncommitted blobs. HTH.

Comment: Alright I'll stick to this then :) Thanks for taking the time mate! I just hope Azure develops a upload handler that manages incomplete blobs!